# Two ip helper for two different services?

Tags: cisco, ip, dhcp

There is a vlan5 currently configured with an ip helper-address to forward the broadcast traffic to our DHCP on a different vlan. Works perfectly and everyone is happy.

```
interface Vlan5
 description Super Vlan 5
 ip address 10.5.0.254 255.255.0.0
 ip helper-address 10.2.41.1 (dhcp)
 ip helper-address 10.2.41.7 (netboot server, DeployStudio)
!
```

By default, DHCP packets are forwarded (with the ip helper-address), along with other common broadcast traffic.

I'm a little bit concern if that could cause any problems on the long term ? Is there any point to forward all the broadcast packets to the dhcp ? (useless since he doesn't need EVERYTHING when a machine is requesting to netboot ?)

Is there any way to decide which type of broadcast packets goes to which machine ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ip-helper doesn't forward all broadcasts, just these UDP ports:

```
Protocol   UDP Port

Time      37
TACACS    49
DNS       53
BOOTP-S   67
BOOTP-C   68
TFTP      69
NetBIOS N 137
NetBIOS D 138
IEN-116   42
```

You can disable some of these with the command

```
no ip forward-protocol udp <port number>
```

But I don't know of a way to forward to different hosts.

Comment: It actually forwards the allowed protocols to all the addresses in `ip helper-address` statements on an interface.

Comment: Right, but you can't forward BOOTP to one host and NetBios to another.

Comment: Exactly, it sends any allowed to all the configured addresses.

Comment: @RonMaupin So I don't need to no ip forward-protocol udp the useless ones ? (let's say TACAS, since the DHCP doesn't care that kind of packet)